# Regular Icosahedron - How much to rotate X, Y, Z to get from face to face?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, polygons, polyhedra, platonic-solids

I have a regular icosahedron shape in Adobe After Effects. I want to start out with the one side flush with the camera, then have the rotations end with another face (adjacent) flush with the camera.

I can adjust X, Y, and Z rotation, in degrees (0-360).

What values should I put to cause a perfect rotation to flush with another face?

**Further information:**

[image: More Information]

The first (2-fold) is what is shown at (x=0,y=0,z=0) rotation. 3-fold is where we want to start and finish the rotation. I think I got to 3-fold with (x=70,y=0,z=0), but I am not sure it is perfect.

Thanks for being awesome!!

Comment: To go from a face to neighboring face, rotate about an axis (through the icosahedron's center) parallel to the edge common to the faces, by an angle equal to the *supplement* of the dihedral angle between the faces. As indicated in Wikipedia's ["Regular icosahedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron), the dihedral angle is $\operatorname{arccos}(-\sqrt{5}/3)=138.189\ldots^\circ$, so you'd rotate by about $41.811^\circ$.

Comment: @blue Rotating by one angle does not lead to the new side being flush as the question requires. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Douglas Rotating once *does* lead to the new side being "flush"---blue is giving is that the angle of rotation and specifying the axis. What you seem to be looking for is a sequence of rotations around the given coordinate axes that results in the rotation Blue specified, but their comment gets you halfway there, since there's a standard procedure for getting from an explicit rotation to the triple of angles you want. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514102/10708539

Comment: Here, the target rotation is a sequence of coordinate-axis rotations. Consider the "3-fold" image; let $x$-, $y$, and $z$-axes be horizontal, vertical, and perpendicular-to-screen. To bring the "lower" neighbor to the front, rotate $\sim 42^\circ$ about the $x$-axis (perhaps followed by a $z$-rotation to make the new front face point the same way as the old). For the upper-left neighbor, first rotate $120^\circ$ (ccw) about $z$, then do the previous $x$-rotation, then rotate *back* by $120^\circ$ (cw) about $z$. If AfterEffects can compose these sequences into a single rotation, you're done.